# How to show the line break button in Android keypad?

Tags: java, android, android-keypad

I am building a text area in my APP using a `TextInputLayout` and its multiline property to let the users write more than 1 line, I am building it programatically (no xml)

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(context);
textInputLayout.setLayoutParams(new TextInputLayout.LayoutParams(TextInputLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TextInputLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

TextInputEditText field = new TextInputEditText(context);
field.setText(text);
field.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
field.setLayoutParams(new TextInputLayout.LayoutParams(TextInputLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,(int) (100 * dp)));
textInputLayout.addView(field);
myLinearLayout.addView(textInputLayout); // add text to layout
```

The code above makes my textarea, but is not showing the `line break` button, it shows a `submit` button instead.

This is the current result:

[image]

This is the expected result (from another app):

[image]

Which property I have to add to show the line break button like the second image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945767/how-to-get-the-keyboard-to-show-a-return-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to get the keyboard to show a return key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945767/how-to-get-the-keyboard-to-show-a-return-key)

Try setting IMEOptions as None.

```
field.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE);
```

Also check if the EditText has become SingleLine that also causes the done button to appear.

Comment: I tried and the "return" button appeared, but when I press it, is inserting spaces instead of line breaks, I wonder if is like you said (EditText turned into a SingleLine?)

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, I had to add `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT`, I going to edit the question, Thank you!

Comment: Great. Even I didnt know that. Good to know.  :)
This could work in other scenarios.

field.setLines(10); 

Will give 10 lines to the user.

But your solution looks neat.